# workable php 7.4 function in joomla 3.10 is working weird in php 8.0

Tags: php, mysql

Am displaying list of news haviing

```
Date

News Heading

Short Descrption
```

The list is spread to around 100 pages, having 20 news in each page

**Issue is**: This is working absolute fine in php 7.4.x in joomla 3.10 where on clicking url - list is shown spread over multiple pages having sort by date wise as first criteria, latest date of publishing is coming

But when same used on php 8.0.x - its showing incorrectly, where on clicking URL - last page of list having page number 100 is shown first. Now when i add on limitstart=0 in url then its showing correctly as the first page.

Seems like URL when opened is directly taking to last page of first most news item as published (although no limitstart is mentioned in it)

Below is code of views/list/tmpl/default.php

```
if(count($this->items) >0){
    //$i=1;
    
    foreach($this->items as $newslist)
    {
        $date = JFactory::getDate($newslist->n_date);
        $list .='<h3><strong>'.$newslist->v_heading.'</strong></h3>
        <p>'. $date->format('F j, Y').'</p>
        <p>'.substr($newslist->v_short_description,0,100).'</p>
        <p><i>Know More on:- </i><a href="index.php?option=com_news&view=detail&v_id='.$newslist->id.'&Itemid='.$Itemid.'"><b><i>'.$newslist->v_heading.'</i></b></a></p><hr/><br>';
                
        //$i=$i+1;
    }
}else{
        JError::raiseError(404, "Message");
    
}

<?php echo $list?>
```

**and for models/list.php this is the function**

```
protected function getListQuery()
    {
        // Create a new query object.
        $db    = $this->getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        // Select the required fields from the table.
        $query
            ->select(
                $this->getState(
                    'list.select', 'DISTINCT a.*'
                )
            );

        $query->from('`#__news` AS a');
                
        if (!JFactory::getUser()->authorise('core.edit', 'com_news'))
        {
            $query->where('a.state = 1');
        }

        // Filter by search in title
        $search = $this->getState('filter.search');

        if (!empty($search))
        {
            if (stripos($search, 'id:') === 0)
            {
                $query->where('a.id = ' . (int) substr($search, 3));
            }
            else
            {
                $search = $db->Quote('%' . $db->escape($search, true) . '%');
                $query->where('( a.n_heading LIKE ' . $search . ' )');
            }
        }
        
/*
        // Add the list ordering clause.
        $orderCol  = $this->state->get('list.ordering');
        $orderDirn = $this->state->get('list.direction');

        if ($orderCol && $orderDirn)
        {
            $query->order($db->escape($orderCol . ' ' . $orderDirn));
        }
*/      //Order by date
        
        $query->order ('a.n_date DESC');
        $query->order ('a.id DESC');
        
        return $query;
    }
```

Unsure how to achieve in and why its not working in php 8.0 where Date wise should be shown on clicking url in descending order
Any help on above !!